# How do I quickly calculate a Bayes classifier?

Tags: probability, bayesian, naive-bayes

With the data from [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/naive-bayes-classifier-81d512f50a7c)  I want to quickly answer the following exam question:

> Given that it is rainy, not windy, the temperature is hot and humidity
> is normal, should you play golf or not?
> Show all workings of solutions to arrive at your final answers.
> (calculate the exact, not proportional, probability values to make your decision and round them to 3 decimal places to make comparisons)

In reading about Bayes I found the following formula helpful

$$
posterior = \frac {prior \cdot likelihood} {evidence} 
$$

I constructed the following as a summary of the data

[image: table summary]

I found the table helpful in preventing counting mistakes ( since the totals need to agree ) 
So applying the formula:

$$post(G) = \frac {prior(G) \cdot likelihood(G|R,H,N,!W)} {evidence} $$
$$post(!G) = \frac {prior(!G) \cdot likelihood(!G|R,H,N,!W) } {evidence}$$
And calculating:
$$prior(G) = \frac{9}{14}$$
$$prior(!G)=\frac{5}{14}$$
$$likelihood(G|R,H,N,!W) =   \frac{2}{9} \cdot \frac{2}{9} \cdot \frac{6}{9} \cdot \frac{6}{9} = \frac{16}{729}$$
$$likelihood(!G|R,H,N,!W) =   \frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{5} = \frac{12}{625}$$
I get:
$$numerator(G)=\frac{9}{14} \cdot \frac{16}{729} \approx 0.0141$$
$$numerator(!G)=\frac{5}{14} \cdot \frac{12}{625} \approx 0.00686$$
$$evidence = numerator(G)+numerator(!G) = 0.021 $$
so $$post(G) = \frac{.0141}{.021} =0.674$$ and
$$post(!G) = \frac{.00686}{.021} =0.327$$

My questions about this question are as follows;

- Have I constructed the Naive Bayes Classifier?
- If so, what part of these equations is the actual "classifier"?
- Do I need to calculate the evidence to properly answer the question?
- Could I just say the odds are 141 to 69 that I should play golf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have I constructed the Naive Bayes Classifier?

Yes, you have. Because, your likelihood calculation was
$$P(R,H,N,W'|G)=P(R|G)P(H|G)P(N|G)P(W'|G)$$

> If so, what part of these equations is the actual "classifier"?

The classifier compares $P(G|R,H,N,W')$ vs $P(G'|R,H,N,W')$ and picks the larger one. This comparison is the classification action. In Bayes/Naive Bayes, we typically don't calculate the denominator since it is the same for both, which answers your third question.

> Could I just say the odds are 141 to 69 that I should play golf?

Correct.